# How to manually set a roaming network (Pixel 2)

Tags: settings, roaming, google-pixel-2

I am having trouble setting a specific roaming network on my Pixel 2. These are my options in the Mobile Network settings. Does anyone know how to set the roaming network here?

[image: Mobile network settings]
[image: Network operator setting search]

Comment: So right now I'm connected to a roaming network A. But I want specify connect to mobile network B.

Comment: Thanks @beeshyams. I don't have "Choose network operators" in my "Mobile Network" settings. See the image I posted at the top.

Comment: Pixel 2, Android 8.1.0, Security patch July 5th 2018

Comment: Thanks @beeshyams. I've added an image to my top post searching for 'network operator' -- unfortunately nothing found. Yeah I have looked into the solution you posted with dialing '*#*#*4636#*#*' but the problem is these network operators have the same network type / bands.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out. The secret was setting the 'Preferred network type' from 'Global' to 'LTE / GSM / UMTS'. That displayed the 'Automatically select network' toggle which I disabled in order to select my desired network. See image below. Thanks for your help, beeshyams!

[image: Mobile network settings]